# MySQL trabalha com mais de um índice?

Tags: mysql, índices

Se eu tenho uma consulta em uma tabela:

```
SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE empresa_id=10 AND datacad='2017-01-01'
```

E dois índices, sendo um na coluna `'empresa_id'` e outro na `'datacad'`.

O MySQL vai usar somente um dos dois, ou é capaz de usar os dois?
Seria melhor criar um índice `'empresa_id, datacad'` ?

Comment: Somente empresa_id é índice, a cláusula where não trabalha somente com índice

Answer (score 1):

Você pode adicionar o `EXPLAIN` no início de sua `query`. Você vai conseguir ver quais as possíveis `keys` que a consulta pode usar e qual está usando, no seu caso você está usando apenas o `índice` relacionado a `empresa_id`, caso queira trocar você pode forçar a utilização de um `índice`colocando após o nome tabela a instrução `USE INDEX (nome_do_indice)`. Para usar um `índice`composto você deve criar um referente as duas colunas. por exemplo:

```
CREATE INDEX `empresa_id_data_cad_idx` ON clientes(empresa_id, data_cad);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Arllon, perfeita explicação!